# ¿Cómo pasar una variable de un método a otro en VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Necesito pasar una propiedad a un metodo desde otro metodo pero al retornar la propiedad no muestra nada pero tampoco manda error

```
<script>
export default {
 methods: {
   signFailed(error) {
     const http_code = error.response.status;
     switch (http_code) {
        case 404:
          console.log("No existe el usuario") 
        break;
        case 401:
          //Aqui es donde estoy tratando de pasar la variable al otro metodo pero no lo he logrado
          this.passwordError('Contraseña incorrecta')
        break;
     }
   }
   //Este es el metodo que recibe la propiedad
   passwordError(errorSwitch) {
     return errorSwitch
   }
 }
}
</script>
```

si me pudieran apoyar colegas se los agradeceria
Saludos

Comment: Si pudieras explicarlo de manera más sencilla, no te entendi

Comment: Listo para ver si me doy a entender

Comment: Es porque tu método passwordError no hace nada más que retornar la variable, osea que es lo que quieres que haga ese metodo?